# How do I keep the last 10 entries and delete the rest?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

User has more than 20 records in a table. I only want to keep the last 10 entries. Which means I want to delete the rest.

I want to do this for each user in that table as well.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Item.destroy(Item.order('created_at').all.last(10).map(&:id))
```

There's probably a less expensive way to do it, but that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks. Through your example. I was able to shorten it to: `items.destroy(items.order('created_at desc') - items.first(10))`